# How To Minimize Your Chrome Browser With Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I Want To Know How to Minimize My Chrome Window in selenium

I Don't Want How To Maximize Because I Know how to maximize chrome window!

Here is my code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')

options.add_argument("--incognito")

options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery");

options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('website.com')
driver.delete_all_cookies()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should works with:

```
driver.minimize_window()
```

Invokes the window manager-specific ‘minimize’ operation

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try:

```
driver.minimize_window()
```